# Code returns a type mismatch when there is "If statement" used

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a code

```
Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
        
        Set myrange1 = wsDest.Range("A:A") 'to be changed to select current range
        en = wsCopy.Range("c4").Value
        st = myrange1.Find(en)
        st1 = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value
        MsgBox st
```

which runs fine and returns the right value in the msgbox,

But when I edit it to include a "If statement" it gives me a Type mismatch error on line "If St is Nothing Then"

st is set as 'Long'

Can someone please help me!

```
Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
        
        Set myrange1 = wsDest.Range("A:A") 'to be changed to select current range
        en = wsCopy.Range("c4").Value
        st = myrange1.Find(en)
        st1 = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value            
        
        If st Is Nothing Then
            Resume
        Else
            Do While st1 <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
                If (st.Offset(0, 4) = st1) Then
                    MsgBox "Leave Request already exists"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                st1 = st1 + 1
                st = myrange1.FindNext(st)
            Loop
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not already there, put this at the top of your code window:

`Option Explicit`

Try to remember to put this at the top of every code window. This will force you to declare variables before using them.

You will need to declare the variable `st` with an explicit type (as well as other variables), like so:

`Dim st As Range`

Then when using the `Range.Find` method, you will need to use the `Set` keyword:

`Set st = myrange1.Find(en)`

Comment: And get into the habit of naming variables properly https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/vba-declare-variable/

Comment: Thanks FlexYourData, that helped a lot. I'm still new to this and really appreciate you taking the time to answer such a basic question !!!

Comment: Basic is relative to each of our experiences. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I promise I will do better !!!